# $Lookup between 4 collections that 3 of them with ObjectId and the 4th one is String produces empty array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm doing a $lookup between 4 collections :

```
Client.aggregate(
      [
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "clientboughtleads",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "Client", // Client is "ObjectId"
            as: "ClientLeads"
          }
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "clientprofiles",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "client", // client is "ObjectId"
            as: "ClientProfile"
          }
        },

        {
          $addFields: {
            TotalPurchasedLeads: {
              $size: "$ClientLeads"
            }
          }
        },

        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "clientscreditloggers",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "ClientId", // ClientId is "String"
            as: "ClientsCreditLoggers"
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            ClientId: "$_id",
            RegistrationDate: "$date",
            TotalPurchasedLeads: 1,
            PurchasedLeadsWorth: {
              $multiply: [LEAD_PRICE, "$TotalPurchasedLeads"]
            },
            ClientType: "$ClientProfile.ClientType",
            ClientsCreditLoggers: "$ClientsCreditLoggers" // This one always empty
            // IncomeFromClient: { $sum: "$ClientsCreditLoggers.AmountBought" }
          }
        }
      ]
```

1. Collection `Client` has an ObjectId ,
2. Collection `clientboughtleads` also has an ObjectId ,
3. Collection `clientprofiles` likewise.
4. Collection `clientscreditloggers` has a `ClientId` as a string

When I $lookup all 4 of them together , the array `ClientsCreditLoggers` is empty.

How can we $lookup also the `clientscreditloggers` collection with the rest ?

Comment: Data type doesn't offer any advantage for `$lookup`, only indexing. In you case, `Client._id` is `ObjectId`, but `clientscreditloggers.ClientId` is string... It's like doing `inner join with 1 = "1", will return nothing`. Change to [uncorrelated subqueries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace your third `$lookup` with below one ([custom pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries)) and use [$toObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toObjectId/index.html) to convert `String` ids:

```
{
      $lookup: {
        from: "clientscreditloggers",
        let: { local_id: "$_id" },
        pipeline: [ { $match: { $expr: { $eq: [ { $toObjectId: "$ClientId" }, "$$local_id" ] } } } ],
        as: "ClientsCreditLoggers"
    }
 }
```